# How to delete Fruit Ninja high score without deleting app?

Tags: ios, fruit-ninja

In Fruit Ninja (on iOS), I recently won the tournament blade and played with it. Unfortunately, it kinda ruined the other blades for me because I can't hope to match its score with anything else. How can I delete the high score without resetting my progress?